# Installation must be finished from the original IP address, sorry - Moodle

Tags: database, amazon-ec2, installation, moodle

I'm trying to install moodle on AWS ec2 and the database is local on ec2 instance and now I'm stuck at error "Installation must be finished from the original IP address, sorry." I have tried all possible solutions on the web but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Just comment out these 3 lines and reload:

```
        if ($adminuser->lastip !== getremoteaddr()) {
            print_error('installhijacked', 'admin');
        }
```

https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/admin/index.php#L753-L755

Answer (score 1):

With all due respect, commenting out core Moodle code is not a good idea, especially when there is an easy and safe work around the problem.

When it comes to AWS EC2, commenting out the code may get you past that point in the installation however, the Moodle **getremoteaddr()** function, which is used everywhere in Moodle, will continue to report an incorrect IP address in things like logs and may even affect the security of your website.

A better approach is to simply add the following line to your Moodle main config.php found in the webroot. It should be placed anywhere between the **$CFG = new stdClass();** and **require_once(__DIR__ . '/lib/setup.php');** lines:

```
$CFG->getremoteaddrconf = 0;
```

This will need to be added anytime up to when you get the error message.

While I have not tried it myself, you may alternatively be able to add the following line to a file called **/local/defaults.php** (create if it does not already exist):

```
$defaults['moodle']['getremoteaddrconf'] = 0; // New default for $CFG->getremoteaddrconf.
```

For more information on defaults.php, see https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Local_plugins#Customised_site_defaults

This **defaults.php** file can be useful for setting default settings during a new installation if you include it in your Moodle fork.

Hope you find this information helpful.

Best regards,

Michael Milette